# Is there a R function to strsplit specifc rows under one column based on another column?

Tags: r, lapply, strsplit

I am having a data frame (for example as below:

```
name  student_id   age  gender
Sam   123_abc_ABC  20   F
John  234_bcd_BCD  18   M
Mark  345_cde_CDE  20   M
Ram   xyz_111_XYZ  19   M
Hari  uvw_444_UVW  23   M
```

Now, I need a new column as student_id_by_govt in the df. The student_id_by_govt is within the student_id but it is different for different names. For Sam, John, Mark the student_id_by_govt would be first segment of student_id (i.e., 123, 234, 345) but for Ram & Hari, the student_id_by_govt is second segment in the student_id (i.e.,111, 444).

I used the strsplit, lapply commands to get the specfic segment from the student_id but I could not able to apply that command specifically for specific rows to get the desired output mentioned above. Please let me know how to get the output as below:

```
name  student_id   age  gender student_id_by_govt
Sam   123_abc_ABC  20   F      123
John  234_bcd_BCD  18   M      234
Mark  345_cde_CDE  20   M      345
Ram   xyz_111_XYZ  19   M      111
Hari  uvw_444_UVW  23   M      444
```

Comment: So you want to extract the numbers from `student_id`?

Comment: It looks like you always want the numbers, which is straightforward. But in your title you say "based on another column", but there doesn't seem to be a consistent rule where we could do something like `if (other_column == x) {first_segment} else{second_segment}`. You say *"apply that command specifically for specific rows"*, but surely you don't want to list out the names for one way and the names for the other??

Comment: If you just want to extract the digits from each ID, the following would work (if your data frame is called "df"): `gsub('\\D', '', df$student_id)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need `str_extract`:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  mutate(student_id_by_govt = str_extract(student_id, "\\d+"))
# A tibble: 5 × 3
  Name  student_id  student_id_by_govt
  <chr> <chr>       <chr>             
1 Sam   123_abc_ABC 123               
2 John  234_bcd_BCD 234               
3 Mark  345_cde_CDE 345               
4 Ram   xyz_111_XYZ 111               
5 Hari  uvw_444_UVW 444
```

**EDIT**:

If the `student_id_by_govt` is determined by `gender`, as OP notes in comment: "for all the 'M' gender, the `student_id_by_govt` is first segment in the `student_id` (ie., 234, 345, xyz, uvw) but for 'F' `gender` I want the second segment of `student_id` (i.e., abc)", then this works:

```
df %>%
  mutate(student_id_by_govt = ifelse(gender == "M", str_extract(student_id, "^[^_]+"),
                                     str_extract(student_id, "(?<=_)[^_]+(?=_)")))
  name  student_id age gender student_id_by_govt
1  Sam 123_abc_ABC  20      F                abc
2 John 234_bcd_BCD  18      M                234
3 Mark 345_cde_CDE  20      F                cde
4  Ram xyz_111_XYZ  19      M                xyz
5 Hari uvw_444_UVW  23      M                uvw
```

Here, we essentially rely on the negative character class `[^_]+`, which matches any character but the underscore one or more times as well as positive lookbehind `(?<=_)`(meaning "*match only if there is an underscore to the left*") and lookahead `(?=_)`(meaning "*match only if there is an underscore to the right*").

Data for solution in **EDIT**:

```
df <- read.table(text="name  student_id   age  gender
Sam   123_abc_ABC  20   F
John  234_bcd_BCD  18   M
Mark  345_cde_CDE  20   F
Ram   xyz_111_XYZ  19   M
Hari  uvw_444_UVW  23   M", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Hi there, is there a code for getting student_id_by_govt column based on gender column? I mean for all the 'M' gender, the student_id_by_govt is first segment in the student_id (ie., 234, 345, xyz, uvw) but for 'F' gender I want the second segment of student_id (i.e., abc) as student_id_by_govt? Please note, the segments I want from student_id in my original data is not numeric.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex via the function **str_extract** from the library **stringr**:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)

df <- tibble(Name = c("Sam", "John", "Mark", "Ram", "Hari"), student_id = c("123_abc_ABC", "234_bcd_BCD", "345_cde_CDE", "xyz_111_XYZ", "uvw_444_UVW")) %>%
      mutate(student_id_by_gvt = map_chr(student_id, function(x){str_extract(x, "(\\d+)")}))
```

Here is the output:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  Name  student_id  student_id_by_gvt
  <chr> <chr>       <chr>            
1 Sam   123_abc_ABC 123              
2 John  234_bcd_BCD 234              
3 Mark  345_cde_CDE 345              
4 Ram   xyz_111_XYZ 111              
5 Hari  uvw_444_UVW 444
```

I am more confortable the tidyverse package. I hope this solution will help you

Comment: Hi there, is there a code for getting student_id_by_govt column based on gender column? I mean for all the 'M' gender, the student_id_by_govt is first segment in the student_id (ie., 234, 345, xyz, uvw) but for 'F' gender I want the second segment of student_id (i.e., abc) as student_id_by_govt? Please note, the segments I want from student_id in my original data is not numeric.

Comment: Do you want this?

Answer (score 0):

Another option using `parse_number` to extract all numbers from a string:

```r
df <- read.table(text="name  student_id   age  gender
Sam   123_abc_ABC  20   F
John  234_bcd_BCD  18   M
Mark  345_cde_CDE  20   M
Ram   xyz_111_XYZ  19   M
Hari  uvw_444_UVW  23   M", header = TRUE)

library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
  mutate(student_id_by_govt = readr::parse_number(as.character(student_id)))
#>   name  student_id age gender student_id_by_govt
#> 1  Sam 123_abc_ABC  20      F                123
#> 2 John 234_bcd_BCD  18      M                234
#> 3 Mark 345_cde_CDE  20      M                345
#> 4  Ram xyz_111_XYZ  19      M                111
#> 5 Hari uvw_444_UVW  23      M                444
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Hi there, is there a code for getting student_id_by_govt column based on gender column? I mean for all the 'M' gender, the student_id_by_govt is first segment in the student_id (ie., 234, 345, xyz, uvw) but for 'F' gender I want the second segment of student_id (i.e., abc) as student_id_by_govt? Please note, the segments I want from student_id in my original data is not numeric.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand what you want.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)

df <- tibble(Name = c("Sam", "John", "Mark", "Ram", "Hari"), student_id = c("123_abc_ABC", "234_596_BCD", "345_cde_CDE", "xyz_111_XYZ", "uvw_444_UVW"), Gender = c("F", "M", "M", "M", "M")) %>%
      # mutate(student_id_by_gvt = if_else(Gender == "M", str_split(student_id, "_")[[1]][1], str_split(student_id, "_")[[1]][2]))
    mutate(student_id_by_gvt = map2_chr(Gender, student_id, function(x,y){if_else(x == "M", str_split(y, "_")[[1]][1], str_split(y, "_")[[1]][2])}))
```

It gives the output:

```
 Name  student_id  Gender student_id_by_gvt
  <chr> <chr>       <chr>  <chr>            
1 Sam   123_abc_ABC F      abc              
2 John  234_596_BCD M      234              
3 Mark  345_cde_CDE M      345              
4 Ram   xyz_111_XYZ M      xyz              
5 Hari  uvw_444_UVW M      uvw
```

Answer (score 0):

since you changed the question in one of your follow up comments quite a bit ie to    "Hi there, is there a code for getting student_id_by_govt column based on gender column? I mean for all the 'M' gender, the student_id_by_govt is first segment in the student_id (ie., 234, 345, xyz, uvw) but for 'F' gender I want the second segment of student_id (i.e., abc) as student_id_by_govt? Please note, the segments I want from student_id in my original data is not numeric."
here is a simple base R solution for the case that the segments are of equal
length and the positions of those segments are stable - in case the strings have differing length but have certain characters based on which you could identify the segments you could replace that `substr` with some `regex` function.

```
df$student_id_by_govt <- ifelse(df$gender == "M", 
                          substr(df$student_id, 1,3), substr(df$student_id, 5,7))
```